# Cast a null into something?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, nullable, dbnull

I had this interesting discussion today with a colleague. We were debating two pieces of code in C#.

Code Snippet 1:

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(2))
{
  long? variable1 = reader.GetInt64(2)
}
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
long variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? (long?) null : reader.GetInt64(2)
```

Question is: is it a good practice to cast null into a nullable long? Or would you rather use the traditional if statement to avoid casting `null` to nullable long.

Comment: Well the cast is for the Conditional Operator you use, it needs the return type of the branches to be similar and snippet2 is compiler error you need it to be `long? variable1`

Comment: As V4Vendetta said, in your second snippet your lh and rh types are different.

Comment: In snippet1, `variable1` only exists inside the `if`'s scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expressions `(type?)null`, `default(type?)` and `new Nullable<type>()` end up being compiled into the same opcodes:

```
        long? x = (long?)null;
        long? y = default(long?);
        long? z = new Nullable<long>();
```

is turned into:

```
    IL_0001: ldloca.s x
    IL_0003: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64>
    IL_0009: ldloca.s y
    IL_000b: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64>
    IL_0011: ldloca.s z
    IL_0013: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64>
```

In other words, if you are working with nullable types, you are free to use whichever version you like best. Note however, that you should try to avoid arithmetics with nullable types. If you want to return a nullable value from a conditional expression, both possible results must be nullable if one of them can be null. Any other way could cause an exception in that case.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: The expression `null as type?` is also compiled into that same IL code. In fact, `null` need not be casted explicitly if the surrounding expression provides a nullable type context, e.g. `condition ? null : value as type?`. The `null` in that expression is also compiled to the `new Nullable<type>()` IL code.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
(long?) null
```

use

```
default(long?)
```

I would refactor above code like

```
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? default(long?) : reader.GetInt64(2)
```

Comment: Why are you using second brackets around `long?` ?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to cast `null` value (it looks odd to me):

```
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : (long?)reader.GetInt64(2);
```

Another options:

```
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? default : reader.GetInt64(2); // requires C# 7.1
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? default(long?) : reader.GetInt64(2);
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? (long?)null : reader.GetInt64(2);
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? new Nullable<long>() : reader.GetInt64(2);
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? new long?() : reader.GetInt64(2);
long? variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : new long?(reader.GetInt64(2));
```

It's just the matter of taste. I think first option is more readable, than others.

UPDATE: Consider also writing some extension methods to make your code more clear:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static long? GetNullableInt64(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(index))
            return null;

        return reader.GetInt64(index);
    }
}
```

In this case you don't use ternary operator (no casting to nullable), and reading values from reader looks more pretty:

```
long? variable1 = reader.GetNullableInt64(2);
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Coz you **cannot convert null to long?**

Comment: @V4Vendetta I fixed this typo before your first comment

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you still have it up there `...? null : (long?)reader.GetInt64(2)` :(

Comment: @V4Vendetta up there `long? variable1`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Do you have compiler near you , it should give no implicit conversion between <null> and long (you have to cast the null in your expression) Hope you get my point ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta can you show me the place where casting between `null` and `long` occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Snippet 2 is worth in my case, as in case of `null` you're gonna get `0`, which is a completely valid value for `long`

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7.1 you can use the [more concise `default` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference):

```
var variable1 = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? default : reader.GetInt64(2);
```