# Initialize variable with null casted to variable's datatype

Tags: c#, types, casting, null

I ran across some code like this:

```
List<string> list = (List<string>)null;
```

Is there some reason the programmer didn't just initialize by:

```
List<string> list = null;
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Is this a habit that migrated from another programming language? Maybe C, C++, or Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast a null into something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633946/cast-a-null-into-something)

Comment: I disagree, that is not a duplicate of my question.

Comment: As the answers state, there is no difference in your lines of code. I believe it could be the effect of a refactoring tool as well, an example could be that originally `var` was used instead of explicit typing, and the refactoring tool just replace `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the two?

No there is no difference.

In [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), This line `List<string> list = (List<string>)null;` changes into  `List<string> list = null;`

> Is this a habit that migrated from another programming language?

Can't say. May be, earlier there was something different than `null` and then it was changed to `null`.

```
List<string> list = (List<string>) Session["List"];
```

Comment: I was wondering if maybe C/C++ or Java required the casting of null. But I suppose it's possible that he replaced some code with the null.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, there is no practical difference, and both assignments will compile down to exactly the same MSIL opcodes. *However*, there is one case where casting a null does make a difference, and that's when calling an overloaded method.

```
class A { }
class B { }

class C
{
    public static void Foo( A value );
    public static void Foo( B value );
}
```

Simply calling `C.Foo( null );` is ambiguous, and the compiler can't reason about which you intend to invoke, but if you cast the null first: `C.Foo( (A)null );`, it's now clear that you mean to call the first overload, but pass it a null instead of an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between those two lines of code. It's matter of taste I think. Although if you use casting, you can remove the type from your variable, like this:

```
var list = (List<string>)null;
```

Without casting you can't do it.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you use the `var` keyword, and then cast to the type you want to define in the first place?

Comment: Well it's one possibility :) Matter of taste too I guess. I would prefer List<string> list = null; myself.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the above case, you don't need the cast. You only need it in an ternary expression like this:

```
return somecondition ? new List<string>() : (List<string>)null;
```

Comment: I think the cast is redundant, you can do it like this: return somecondition ? new List<string>() : null;

Comment: I can't test it now, but it seems that even in your sample cast is useless

Comment: Commenters are correct, you don't need to cast, you can return `null` from a method that returns List<string>.